# Datatree MUMPS -- resolve undefined variables to null/empty string?

Tags: variables, undefined, mumps

I'm trying to port some scripts from a modern version of Intersystems Cache back to 1980s Datatree MUMPS.  It was written in the context where $ZUTIL(18,2) was set.  That is, undefined variables resolve to an empty string, rather than throwing an "undefined variable" error.

Rather than refactor it all to check $DATA, does anyone know whether DTM supports a similar feature to automatically resolve undefined variables per process, or globally?

*Update: running "zzswitch +2" did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was tricky one.

Have a look at this document:

ftp://ftp.intersystems.com/pub/cache/DTMtoCache.doc95

It says that equivalent of $ZU(18) in DTM was zzswitch +2 / -2

I obviously can't run DTM now so just try to issue zzswitch +2 and then zzswitch -2 and see how does it affect the way your undefined vars are treated.

PS: I would understand efforts of migrating from DTM to Cache, but going back? Mate it's not even necromancy, it's archeology now.

Comment: At first I tried bringing everything from the DTM system into an evaluation Cache install.  I found too many incompatibilities that way, in comparison to the one thing I wanted ($ZUTIL) for porting the simple scripts.  Might be worth it for future projects, but hopefully there will be few future projects digging around 30 year old systems!  Thanks a lot, zzswitch does the trick.